# Why div's height is 0 even though I have manually set it to be 34.4rem?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to improve my css and html skills as a new frontend developer by mimicking [canva](https://canva.com). Here is my code:

```css
.content {
  height: calc(100vh - 7.2rem);
  overflow: scroll;
  flex: 0 1 80%;
  align-self: stretch;
  background-color: #00DBDE;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #00DBDE 0%, #FC00FF 100%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.search-field {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 99%;
  // width: 99rem;
  height: 34.4rem;
  border-radius: .8rem;
  margin: 3rem auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  &__bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% + 30vh);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    background-image: url(https://banner-static.canva.com/images/c4878dcc-0e7e-453f-adee-4c60971feb3d_20200523-DeskSpaceMint-Global-Desktop-2x.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50%;
  }
  &__front {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    //test
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  &__heading {
    font-size: 4.8rem;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  &__input {}
  &__link {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="content">
  <div class="search-field">
    <div class="search-field__bg"></div>
    <div class="search-field__front">
      <h2 class="search-field__heading">Design anything.</h2>
      <input type="search" class="search-field__input" placeholder='Try "Card"'>
      <svg class="navbar__icon-size-small">
          <use href="/img/svg/sprites.svg#icon-down-arrow"></use>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
      list of items...
  </div>
</section>
```

The question is why does my `div.search-field` disappears even though I have manually set it's height to `34.4rem` and width to `99%`. I have checked the google chrome developer tools by finding that its computed height somehow becomes `0`.

If you want a complete copy of my project, please see [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Beemo-007/pen/RwaRQjo?editors=1100). You might note that there are some imgs and svgs missing because I don't know how to uploaded local imgs to Codepen. The website is hosted on [Netlify](https://beemo.netlify.app/). Much appreciated if you would spend some time on spotting these bugs.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. In order to make your question easier to read and therefore get answers faster, can you please remove all unnecessary code so there is only the relevant code left to reproduce your issue?

Comment: You have a flex style and the search field is minimized to its minimum height of 0; if you add a min height: 3rem; it would become 3 rem.

Comment: It works! What makes it difference between height and min-height?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex
flex-shrink is to control the height in a flexible way... this doesn't affect the min-height.

Comment: @RakibulIslam, sorry but I think that's not really the answer but rather a clarification that something in the layout is not quite right. I'm not good enough with flexboxes to know the correct answer... for me it has more the touch of a workaround - therefore as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Your `.content` class is a flex item. But, the problem is that, in this case, the total height of all the child elements has exceeded the height of `.content`. As it is flex item, it shrinks the childs to create space for other child elements.

To solve this, use `flex-shrink: 0;` in your `.search-field`  class.

> The flex-shrink CSS property sets the flex shrink factor of a flex
> item. If the size of all flex items is larger than the flex container,
> items shrink to fit according to flex-shrink.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Codepen!
It looks like the parent container is trying to shrink its children to their minimum heights, one thing that you could do is leave all of the styles on the children so that you keep the cropping and any positioning you have in place, and on the parent container (.content), remove the flex-direction style and allow the children to wrap:

```
.content {
  height: calc(100vh - 7.2rem);
  overflow: scroll;
  flex: 0 1 80%;
  align-self: stretch;
  background-color: #00DBDE;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #00DBDE 0%, #FC00FF 100%);
  display: flex;
/*   flex-direction: column;  */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can change CSS for div.search-field as below to get desired results

```
.search-field {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 500;
  width: 99%;
  height: 34.4rem;
  min-height: 34.4rem;
  border-radius: .8rem;
  margin: 3rem auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: #85FFBD;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #85FFBD 0%, #FFFB7D 100%); }
```